# Neo4j ORDER BY custom sorting?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a query where a part of it looks like:

```
WITH ... person ORDER BY person.name
```

The issue is that person.name contains the full name i.e. "Albert Einstein". So Albert Einstein appears before "Peter Albert".

Is there a way to do the order by on the persons last name? I.e. some kind of custom comparator? Of course, taking into account one name people like Madonna :).

I know I could go into the data and split all the names, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

Comment: Why would you avoid splitting the data? 
You can of course use a custom sort, but whatever function you use, it will something that has to be evaluated runtime so it will be quite expensive.

Comment: @Graphileon Ya... you'd be doing string splits on every compare. The trade off is that I'm not sure I want the resulting json to have firstName & lastName, probably just name. So in the db, I'd either have to store first & last and then concat them for display or have full name and last name just for ordering. So its either a split vs concat or have a copy of the last name in a hidden field just for sorting I think. Any opinion on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort on the fly but as stated in the comments, it will be expensive compared to splitting the data in the model.

Using the Movies dataset as example, here is a way to sort it based on last name.
Split the name separated by space into a list then [-1] means sort by the last item of that list.

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
WITH n ORDER by split(n.name, ' ')[-1]
RETURN n.name

result:

 ════════════════════════╕
│"n.name"                │
╞════════════════════════╡
│"Stefan Arndt"          │
├────────────────────────┤
│"Kevin Bacon"           │
├────────────────────────┤
│"Christian Bale"        │
├────────────────────────┤
│"Marshall Bell"         │
├────────────────────────┤
│"Halle Berry"           │
```

Comment: Dang... that's a nice trick! But yeah, I guess I'll probably split it out in the model like you guys are suggesting.